# If $X<Y$ then the CDF of $X$ greater then CDF of $Y$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X$ and $Y$ two random varible with 
$$X\leq Y$$ then why $$F_X(x)\geq F_Y(y)$$
I have founded in paper.

[image]

then

[image]

Comment: Write out the definition of $F_X(x) = P(X \le x)$ and the notation for $\{X \le x\} = \{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \le x\}$.  Can you do the same for $Y$ and compare the two?

Comment: I think you mean $F_X(x)\geq F_Y(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you know that if $A$ is true then so is $B.$ In that case $\Pr(A) \le \Pr(B).$

You have $X\le Y$ with probability $1.$

If $Y\le x$ then $X\le x.$

Therefore $\Pr(Y\le x) \le \Pr(X\le x).$

I.e. $F_Y(x) \le F_X(x).$

Comment: i didn't understand If $Y\leq x$ then  $Y \leq x$ 
Therefore $Pr(Y \leq x)c\leq Pr(X \leq x)$ ?.

Comment: Hi, I'm a little confused about some stuff, could you please clarify a couple of things for me? $1)$ Are we assuming that $X, Y$ are random variables corresponding to the same experiment? $2)$ When you say $X \le Y$, do you mean that $\forall x \in \Omega X(x) \le Y(x)$? (I think this makes sense only if the answer to question 1 was "yes") $3)$ When you say $Y \le x$ do you mean that $x$ is fixed and $\forall (y \in range Y) y \le x?$

Comment: @Ovi : The domains of $X$ and $Y$ would have to be the same probability space. Note that I said $X\le Y$ with probability $1.$ The phrase “with probability $1$” implies that the probability of the set $\{\,\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega) \le Y(\omega)\,\}$ has probability $1,$ i.e. it is true of almost all values of $\omega,$ and “almost all” means the measure of the set of points that are exceptions is $0.$ Where I said "If $Y\le x$ then $X\le x$, that means if $x$ is any real number at all then if $Y\le x$ then $X\le x. \qquad$